# retrofit2 patch request does not response with body

Tags: android, retrofit2, patch

I'm working on an application with some endpoints. In summary patch requests when have filled body does not callback and it get timeout error. this event happen just for patch requests and other methods such as GET, POST, PUT and DELETE work fine. other thing is these endpoints all work fine in Postman.

One of my services

```
public interface ApiService {

    @Headers({"Accept: application/json;version=0.1.1",
            "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"})
    @PATCH("api/club/product/{id}/")
    Call<ResponseBody> requestEditProducts(@Header ("Authorization") String token,
                                           @Body RequestBody body,
                                           @Path("id") int id);
}
```

Client class

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {

            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
            httpClient.connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            httpClient.callTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            httpClient.readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            httpClient.writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            httpClient.retryOnConnectionFailure(true);

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Consts.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

One call example

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("name", "new name");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), object.toString());

        Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(ApiService.class)
                .requestEditProducts(token, requestBody, id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d("PATCH_REQUEST", "code: " + response.code() +
                        "             body: " + response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

One calls result

```
D/OkHttp: --> PATCH http://beta.nsme.com/api/club/product/9/
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 41
D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json;version=0.1.1
D/OkHttp: Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
D/OkHttp: {"name":"new name"}
D/OkHttp: --> END PATCH (41-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
W/System.err: java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.timeoutExit(Transmitter.java:109)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.maybeReleaseConnection(Transmitter.java:302)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.noMoreExchanges(Transmitter.java:267)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:237)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:172)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:185)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:250)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:553)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:485)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:358)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:230)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readHeaderLine(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:242)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:213)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.java:115)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:94)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:43)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:212)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
W/System.err:   ... 5 more
```

Comment: requestEditProducts and patchMessage is a different calls. Would you be so kind to post the same request in example. Also I guess you need your  Auth token for patchMessage request

Comment: I made a mistake sorry. post have been edited. 
unfortunately back-end guys do not let me to share a token and urls @EugeneTroyanskii

Comment: Here you have 3 params requestEditProducts(@Header ("Authorization") String token,
                                           @Body RequestBody body,
                                           @Path("id") int id); and when you call this method you put only 2 requestEditProducts(requestBody, id); You can't compile this.

Comment: Ah you are right, I forgot. edited.
Thanks a lot about find mistakes @EugeneTroyanskii

Comment: Does it work in postman?

Comment: Yes it works in postman well, either in devices some times, but most of the times does not work. i create simple project to test just this endpoints and not work again in test project. all request work with local server fine but when i change base_url to published edition the patch requests don't answers.@EugeneTroyanskii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a lot of tests we found the error is occurring due to ISP proxy problems. It cause problem with PATCH method with body.

Comment: Connection errors can't affect only PATCH request:D Btw don't you forget to add permission for internet?

Comment: Are you kidding me? :\ absolutely i added internet permission. But i realy don't know why all request works fine in SIM data and in my wifi mode just PATCH requests does not work. @EugeneTroyanskii

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is that you re-create Retrofit. You have to include this creation to your singleton:

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static ApiService api;

    public static ApiService getInstance() {
        if (api == null) {

            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
            httpClient.connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            httpClient.callTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            httpClient.readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            httpClient.writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            httpClient.retryOnConnectionFailure(true);

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Consts.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();
            api = retrofit.create(ApiService.class)
        }
        return api;
    }
}
```

And then make your call like:

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(ApiService.class).requestEditProducts(token, requestBody, id);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.d("PATCH_REQUEST", "code: " + response.code() +
                    "             body: " + response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
});
```

Comment: sorry, problem caused due to ISP proxy server.